# nvidia driver-510 issue related to nvidia-515

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, nvidia-geforce

A couple of weeks ago apt upgrade on my desktop computer running Ubuntu 20.04 started telling me I had kept-back packages. They were nvidia-510 packages, and one  nvidia-515 package. It seemed odd nvidia-driver-510 should have a dependency on nvidia-driver-515.
At the same time I started having issues with video, like movies not playing smoothly, and typing in an editor not being smooth. I decided to revert to nvidia-driver-470 which is working well on my laptop, but this caused graphics to stop working altogether, taking me back to VGA resolution and disabling additonal displays.

I tried the nvidia-driver-515, no luck. I tried Nouveau, didn't work. After about an hour I managed to fix the issue, I'll post what I did as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I did `sudo apt remove nvidia-driver-515`. Then I did `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. This made the kept-back messages go away. Then I did  `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and I checked the additional drivers. I selected 510 and rebooted, and all is well now.

I don't know what exactly caused the issue, I may have mishandled the kept-back packages. I do know the issue started when nvidia-driver-515 started showing up on my computer.